# What do the Sockets Error mean and how can I fix them?

Tags: python-3.x

I know there are some other questions on Sockets, but nothing really worked for me. I am new to this and I work on Python 3.4.

For my server this is my code:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 80
s.bind(host, port))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Got connection from", addr)
    c.send("Thank you for connecting")
    c.close()
```

My client code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname
port  = 80

s.connect((host, port))
print (s.recv(1024))
s.close
```

For the SERVER code, I got an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Gautam/Documents/server.py", line 6, in <module>
    s.bind((host, port))
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

For the CLIENT I got an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Gautam/Documents/client.py", line 7, in <module>
    s.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Comment: try to run it as administrator

Answer (score 2):

Port numbers below 1024 are reserved for the system, you need to have special privileges to bind sockets to those ports. You need to use another port number, above 1024.

The second error should be pretty simple to figure out, as the error message explicitly say

> Connection refused

As the server won't run, how do you expect the client to connect to it?

---

On a related note, don't use "well-known" port numbers for your own servers, unless you are actually planning to do what the ports are "well-known" for. For example, port 80 is usually used by web-servers, so unless you plan to make a web-server you should not use that port.

Even ports above 1024 are sometimes so called "well-known" ports. Start by checking `/etc/services` to see the port you picked is commonly available. Do note that some services are pretty obscure and not used very much, but you should still avoid using a port number that's already "reserved" according to `/etc/services`.

Comment: I do plan to make a web-server, but what exactly should I change to get the server to work?

Comment: @Gautam0831 If you want to use port numbers below 1024 you need to run with increased privileges, like "Run as administrator" in Windows.

Comment: How can you run with increased privileges in macs? I need to make a web-server, so I want to use port 80

Comment: Now we are into territory that's really off-topic for stackoverflow.com, but I'll tell you anyway. The best and safest solution (IMO) is to use a *real* web-server listening for connections on port 80, and have it configured so that certain URLs are forwarded to your application which can then listen to any non-privileged port. Otherwise you have to run your application as `root` which is a problem security-wise.